# Regex program to search a string with spaces and back slashes performance issue

Tags: java, regex, scala, apache-spark

These are the lines of text I have:

```
Region\ name=Provence\ Alpes\ Cote\ d'Azur shops=350,City=Nice 12345
Region\ name=Provence\ Alpes\ Cote\ d'Azur,City=Nice shopsabcdabcdabcdasssss=350 13456
City=Nice,Region\ name=Provence\ Alpes\ Cote\ d'Azur shopsabcdabcdabcdasssss=350 23456
```

**Input**: Region\ name
**Output**: Provence\ Alpes\ Cote\ d'Azur

**Input**: City
**Output**: Nice

Below solution provides the result:

```
val data =List("Region\\ name=Provence\\ Alpes\\ Cote\\ d'Azur shops=350,City=Nice"
                ,"Region\\ name=Provence\\ Alpes\\ Cote\\ d'Azur,City=Nice shopsabcdabcdabcdasssss=350"
                ,"City=Nice,Region\\ name=Provence\\ Alpes\\ Cote\\ d'Azur shopsabcdabcdabcdasssss=350"
                ,"City=Nice,Region\\ name =unknown shops=350")
               //With that, let's extract all the values where target is the key.
val target  = """Region\\ name"""
val pattern =raw"$target\s*=((?:[\w'\\ -]+)+)(?:[ ,]+\w+=|,|$$)".r.unanchored
val output  = data.collect{ case pattern(m) => m }
```

But it is taking more time or hangs to extract the result by using `.r.unanchored` when there is a long string like `shopsabcdabcdabcdasssss` or `shopsabcdabcdabcdasssssssssssssssssssssss`.

Can it be replaced with better code?
It hs been resolved and thanks for contributing answer

regex101.com/r/nSYxfj/6 ----------->will it work for extracting integer value.Or I have to modify something

Comment: What question do you have ?

Comment: This is clear, there is catastrophic backtracking that needs fixing.

Comment: south,attribute\ MO\ Name=A,MO\ Name=B SA\ Total=98 1590424200000000000                       south,attribute\ MO\ Name=C,MO\ Name=D,SA\ Total=98 1590424200000000000            here user input is attribute\ MO\ Name and MO\ Name   ,and we are using below  regx                                                  val patternRegx =raw"(?<![^,\s])$target\s*=([\w'\\\s-]+)(?:[\s,]+\w+=|,|$$)".r.unanchored      output expected ----> A when attribute\ MO\ Name and B when MO\ Name

Comment: Please re-accept the answer below, it full addresses the original problem. The rest is covered in your other question.

Answer (score 4):

The `((?:[\w'\\ -]+)+)` pattern part causes [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html).

You need to use

```
Region\\ name\s*=([\w'\\\s-]+)(?:[\s,]+\w+=|,|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nSYxfj/1).

In Scala, define the pattern like this:

```
val pattern =raw"$target\s*=([\w'\\\s-]+)(?:[\s,]+\w+=|,|$$)".r.unanchored
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218945/discussion-on-answer-by-wiktor-stribizew-regex-program-to-search-a-string-with-s).