# Regex program to find a Number with spaces and back slashes

Tags: regex, scala

Below regex extracts integers, but one case is failing.

Example strings:

```
Monday,City=Nice,total\ avg\ shops=350,avg\ shops=20 month=jan
Monday,City=Nice total\ avg\ shops=23 avg\ shops=10 month=Feb
Monday,City=Nice total\,avg\ shops=30 avg\ shops=50 month=Feb
Monday total\,avg\,shops=30 avg\ shops=50,City=Nice month=Feb
Region,Network=myTelco total\ avg\ shops=30.0 avg\ shops=20color=Pink 1590424200000000000
```

My regex:

```
(?:(?<![^,])|=\w+\s+)avg\\ shops\s*=([0-9.]+)
```

See [demo link](https://regex101.com/r/nSYxfj/7).

Sample code:

```
 val matcherInt = Pattern.compile(s"(?:(?<![^,\\s])|=\\w+\\s+)$targetz\\s*=([0-9.]+)").matcher(valueInt)
     if (matcherInt.find()) {
      println( matcherInt.group(1))
     } else
      println("Nothing match")
```

Comment: please specify fail case with current output and expected output

Comment: @Anshuman It is clear in the demo link, `Region,Network=myTelco total\ avg\ shops=30.0 avg\ shops=20color=Pink 1590424200000000000` has no match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:,|^|=[\w.]+\s+)avg\\ shops\s*=([0-9.]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/527Hlb/1)

**Details**

- `(?:,|^|=[\w.]+\s+)`
- `avg\\ shops` - `avg shops` string
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `=` - a `=` symbol
- `([0-9.]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits or `.` chars.

Comment: will  be catastrophic backtracking problem occured?

Comment: @santanumohanty No, it cannot occur here: `,`/start of string/`=` + word or dot chars + whitespace chars, then ``avg\ shops``, then 0 or more whitespaces, then `=`, then 1 or more digits or dots - as you see, there are no occurrences of patterns that may start at the same location, the subsequent patterns all match different kind of texts.

Comment: can you please check ,why it is not matched                   https://regex101.com/r/527Hlb/2

Comment: @santanumohanty Because there are not just word or dot chars after `.`, try https://regex101.com/r/527Hlb/3

Comment: if i am getting special charecter like -% etc then its fail , example Region\ name=Provence-abc\ Alpes\ Cote\ d'Azu  https://regex101.com/r/527Hlb/4

Comment: @santanumohanty Try to generalize it by saying *match `=` and then any chars but `=` and whitespace or an escaped space*. `(?:,|^|=(?:[^=\s]|\\ )+\s+)avg\\ shops\s*=([0-9.]+)`, see https://regex101.com/r/527Hlb/5

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/527Hlb/7  giving wrong results .There is no shop alone.It should reject all records

Comment: @santanumohanty If values can contain no comma, try `(?:,|^|=(?:[^,=\s]|\\ )+\s+)shops\s*=([0-9.]+)`. Another guess: only allow matching at the start, after a comma, or space not preceded with backslash: `(?<=^|,|(?<!\\)\s)shops\s*=([0-9.]+)`

Comment: You are rock...I try a lot to break your Regex with different combination of input but unable to do...Its 100% working..Thanks for your time .It is 100% working

Comment: Thanks..It is always working for (?<![^\s,])avg\\ shops\s*=(.*?)(?:[\s,]+\w+=|,|$) for my understanding what is \s* .As I understood if data is avg\ shop=24 or avg\ shop<space> =24,then /s* is useful when there is space before = .Similarly insted of space if I have back slash i.e avg\ shop\=25. then \s*|\\= will work? example Region,Network=myTelco avg\ shops\=36.0,shops=201 .Currently in code I am replacing \= with = and processing. is it handle by Regex .

Comment: regex101.com/r/527Hlb/9

Comment: i did it by (?<=^|,|(?<!\\)\s)Ran\\ accessibility(\\|\s*)=([\w-'.#$@^+*()%`~&=!]+)  for  avg\ shop\=25 or avg\ shop=25 or avg\ shop      =25  .is there any better one

Comment: @santanumohanty Instead of ``\s*|\\=``, you'd better use a character class, `[\s\\]*=`. ``[\w-'.#$@^+*()%`~&=!]+``  is wrong, a fixed version is ``[\w'.#$@^+*()%`~&=!-]+``

Comment: It is working..For word extraction, I am using  (?<=^|,|(?<!\\)\s)Ne\s*=([^,]*?)(?:(?:\s*,)?\s*\w+=|,|\s\d|$$)    =>this one satisfy everything when only allow matching at the start, after a comma only (\, not preceded with backslash), or space not preceded with backslash. example EnergyMeter,Ne=GNB_02\,Equipment\=1\,EnergyMeter\=1,NeType=GNB,Region\ id=fr-pac    ...if user gives Ne o/p should be GNB_02\,Equipment\=1\,EnergyMeter\=1 but it is showing output as GNB_02.

Comment: EnergyMeter,Ne=GNB_02\ Equipment\=1\ EnergyMeter\=1,NeType=xyz  ---it is working correctly when we give Ne it is comming as  GNB_02\ Equipment\=1\ EnergyMeter\=1

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218995/discussion-between-santanu-mohanty-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: regex101.com/r/0nsbCf/1    --one condition is failing..Can you please help me.Condition is that   EnergyMeter,Ne=GNB_02\,Equipment\=1\,EnergyMeter\=1,NeType=GNB  when I want Ne details ,it will give me GNB_02\,Equipment\=1\,EnergyMeter\=1

Comment: IT is clear that, search string will stop when it get comma or space alone.If there is a back slash before that then it goes to next word search

Comment: @santanumohanty Please re-accept [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63079994/3832970), it is fully answers the problem. The current "condition" is not a condition, it is your task. Please stop spamming your own questions. Think of a set of verbal rules that you need to implement as regex. Throwing in millions of example is counterproductive. I can only suggest https://regex101.com/r/w4m6oK/1

Comment: Thank you..It is end of my problem.It is one of the complex patterns I have ever faced. Begining I did not come with all complex data.I am extremly sorry.But you are super inteligent..I think no one can resolved this by regex except  you.I will connect in future in case I get any complex pattern,